# How do I explain the contents of the profile file

Tags: bash, .profile

Examining the contents of `~/.bash_profile` shows:

```
codio@data-burma:~$ cat ~/.bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi

cd /home/codio/workspace
codio@data-burma:~$
```

What does all this code in `.bash_profile` mean?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using a program that emulates Ubuntu, as this is only for my GCSEs

Comment: As [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880110/how-do-i-explain-the-contents-of-the-profile-file#comment1370289_880110) and [Yaron](https://askubuntu.com/a/880113/22949) have suggested, it's unexpected to have a `.bash_profile` file in Ubuntu that looks like this (most often, one doesn't have `.bash_profile` at all, just `.profile`). So please [edit] this to tell what Ubuntu release you are using, the output of `lsb_release -a` and `cat /etc/issue`, and an explanation of how you installed or upgraded Ubuntu. Did you copy your home directory from another machine? Did that machine run Ubuntu?

Comment: @Slayde098 Emulates Ubuntu in what way? What program is this, what operating system is it running on, and (if applicable) how did you configure it?

Comment: It emulates Ubuntu as it just gives the terminal window from a Ubuntu server, the site that I have to use is codio.com

Comment: @Slayde098 Can you explain the relationship between whatever you are using on codio.com and Ubuntu? Are you actually accessing an Ubuntu machine? Please still [edit] this with all the specific information that I (and everyone else) has requested. This will likely be put on hold as *unclear* but if you provide sufficient information then it can be reopened. **Please *[edit]* your question to give this information.** (Not only does this make it way easier for someone who first sees this to see what is going on, but [edit]ing automatically gets a closed qustion considered for reopening.) Thanks.

Comment: Alright, gimme a second

Comment: @EliahKagan, I have a `bash_profile` myself which points to `.bashrc` so AFAIK its normal as I didn't create it.

Comment: @George you can check `/etc/skel` to see which shell initialization files Ubuntu has by default. `.bash_profile` definitely isn't in any default Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @muru, well strange things do happen. Ok where do you suppose it came from?

Comment: @George no idea, only you (and probably your shell history) can say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below answer is based on [.bash_profile vs. .bashrc](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) by [Josh Staiger](http://www.joshstaiger.org/). For more details please review the content of [that page](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).

> According to the bash man page, `.bash_profile` is executed for login
>   shells, while `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells.

> Most of the time you don’t want to maintain two separate config files
>   for login and non-login shells — when you set a `PATH`, you want it to
>   apply to both. You can fix this by sourcing `.bashrc` from your
>   `.bash_profile` file, then putting PATH and common settings in
>   .bashrc.
>
> To do this, add the following lines to `.bash_profile`:
>
> ```
> if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
>    source ~/.bashrc
> fi
> ```

The above code does the following:

1. Check if  `~/.bashrc` exists.
2. If the file exists it, `source` it ("execute it").

Answer (score -1):

### The meaning of the default code in the `~/.profile` file

**The first section:**

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

It's verifying that your shell is `bash`. The `BASH_VERSION` variable is only set when running `bash` so this is an easy way of checking. Then it will source the `~/.bashrc` file if it exist.  The `.bashrc` file does exist on **Ubuntu** installations.  So it will be sourced.  It's this `.bashrc` file that you will put your custom configurations such as special variable settings and aliases.

For instance, if you want to type `cls` to clear your screen, you could alias it with:

```
$ alias cls="clear"
```

After that command, this would clear your screen:

```
$ cls
```

Just add that line to your `.bashrc` file, then the next time you open a terminal you could clear the screen with either `cls` or `clear`.

**The second section:**

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This block is checking if you have created a `~/bin` folder in your **home** folder.  If you have it will add this folder to your execute path.  This way any custom scripts or special commands that you want to type in without using a full path, you could place it there (or a link to it from there) be able to execute the command without typing it the full path.

**Summary**

The `!/.profile` is a script that is run when you log in or start a terminal.  Any commands are settings can be added to the script.  But by default it (1) checks for a `~/.bashrc` file and loads (source) it and (2) checks for a `~/bin` folder and adds it to the default **PATH** if it exists.

**Update:**

I described above the meaning of the content of the **.profile** as provided by Ubuntu by default.  Some systems will have different content.

You have a line in your **.profile** that is different from the default.  As explained it's a script and is run when you log into the system (or run a new **terminal**.).

Your line that reads:

```
cd /home/codio/workspace
```

Changes the current directory to the `/home/codio/workspace`.  This is done at times when a user has a linked home directory and the the prompt shows the full paths of the home directory instead `~$` as the home path.  The other lines have been explained.  Hope this clarifies the custom line added to your the particular **.profile** script included in your question.

Comment: Indeed, but it seems like you didn't read the question body?

Comment: @Zanna I explained the meaning of the content of the **.profile** for how it's used in Ubuntu.  I also explained how to add other commands to do things.  It appears the OP has a line `cd /home/codio/workspace
` added to his **.profile** file.  It performs the way I explained in the original answer, that you can add other commandlines that will be processed.  If there's something else that you think should be clarified in the answer or I'm missing what you are currently pointing out, thanks in advance for calling it to my attention.

Comment: Well, technically the question is about `~/.bash_profile`, which a) doesn't exist by default in Ubuntu, and b) supersedes `~/.profile` if created.

Comment: @muru Thanks.  Now I see.  I was reading the title, and checking my `16.04` installation and explaining the default superseded version.  Looking at one of my older machines I see that `~/.bash_profile` resembles closely the `~/.bashrc`.   It wasn't immediately clear that he wanted specific lines explained.  I thought by the title, he was trying to understand the purpose of the profile file itself.  So I explained the purpose and the meaning of the lines that are in the current version.  Hopefully I'm closer on point, by having included the specific lines question.